# How to run an Airflow DAG that is defined in a test?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to write a test case where I:

- instantiate a collection of (Python)Operators (patching some of their dependencies with `unittest.mock.patch`)
- arrange those Operators in a DAG
- run that DAG
- make assertions about the calls to various mocked downstreams

I see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055151/how-to-trigger-an-airflow-dag-run-from-within-a-python-script/60069511#60069511) that running a DAG is not so simple as calling `dag.run` - I should instantiate a `local_client` and call `trigger_dag` on that. However, the resultant code [constructs its own DagBag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py#L114-L124), and does not accept any parameter that allows me to pass in my manually-constructed DAG - so I cannot see how to run this DAG with `local_client`.

I see a couple of options here:

- I could declare my testing DAG in a separate folder, as specified by `DagModel.get_current(dag_id).fileloc`, so that my DAG will get picked up by `trigger_dag` and so run - but this seems pretty indirect, and also I doubt that I'd be able to cleanly reference the injected mocks from my test code.
- I could directly call `api.common.experimental.trigger_dag._trigger_dag`, which has a `dag_bag` argument. Both the `experimental` in the name, and the underscored-prefixed method name, suggest that this would be A Bad Idea.

Comment: Suggested reads [testing a DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/best-practices.html#testing-a-dag), [`airflow test` CLI command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#id2), [How to test airflow dag in unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50003048/3679900). For advanced stuff, refer to [Testing and debugging Apache Airflow](https://godatadriven.com/blog/testing-and-debugging-apache-airflow/) and [Testing in Airflow (multi-part series)](https://blog.usejournal.com/testing-in-airflow-part-1-dag-validation-tests-dag-definition-tests-and-unit-tests-2aa94970570c)