# Trigger an Airflow DAG in python terminal

Tags: python, airflow, pipeline

May I trigger a DAG in python terminal with a specific parameter?
I have a DAG that runs multiple times a day with some defined parameters.
Example: There is function that manipulates data and publishes a table. It should go back 7 days and read data from the resources and restate the table day by day.
Sometimes I need to restate the data for example for 2 months or even a year. I wish I could do it without changing the DAG.
Is there any way to run a DAG from terminal for example like airflow trigger_dag <DAG_NAME> <arg/parameter>

I wanted to create the exact same pipeline and parameterize that day parameter, set the schedule to None and run the python file in terminal. It is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger an airflow DAG run from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055151/how-to-trigger-an-airflow-dag-run-from-within-a-python-script)

Comment: within python shell you can run these lines one by one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60069511/5739514

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `airflow dags trigger` [command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#trigger) and pass data to the `conf` parameter. This isn't from a Python shell necessarily but can be run from the terminal.

If you must be in a Python shell, you can also use the [Python SDK](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/api/client/local_client.py) or [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run).

Comment: I got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'